# Dynamic model driven forms in Angular 2

Tags: angular, primeng

I have an application with a form where when user selects a value i need to construct additional form inputs based on his selection.
Im getting from the DB the following json

```
[
  {
     "id":1, 
     "typeId":1,
     "fieldName":"Disk Volume",
     "fieldType":"select",
     "fieldValue":"A:,B:,C:,D:,E:,F:",
     "fieldValidation":null
  }
  ,{
     "id":2,
     "typeId":1,
     "fieldName":"Free Space (MB)",
     "fieldType":"input",
     "fieldValue":null,
     "fieldValidation":null
  },
  {
     "id":3,
     "typeId":1,
     "fieldName":"Test Value",
     "fieldType":"checkbox",
     "fieldValue":null,
     "fieldValidation":null
  },
  {
     "id":4,
     "typeId":1,"fieldName":
     "Test Value2",
     "fieldType":"select",
     "fieldValue":"Test1,Test2",
     "fieldValidation":null
   }
]
```

so in this example i will need to create 4 additional fields
two of them are dropdowns with the options setted from the fieldValue property of the json.

Im using primeNg components this way

```
<p-dropdown [options]="permissions" [(ngModel)]="selectedPermission"></p-dropdown>
```

but my issue is that im not sure on how to approach this as i cannot declare the ngModel nor the options...
I've tried looking into FormArray but i understand its used for input text fields, but i may have other types of field

Comment: 2 things:1/ you need to pass an array of SelectItem in the option parameter, something like DBValues.map(value => {label: value.fieldName, value:value})

Comment: 2/ you don't need to create a formArray, you just need a formControl which will get the value selected in the dropdown